# Load data from txt file in HTML

Tags: html, file, text

I have a simple code where

```
<ul id="scroller">
<li>Consulting Manager- China</li>
<li>Junior Business Consultant- Saudi Arabia</li>
<li>Project Manager- Germany</li>
<li>Consulting Manager- Dubai</li>
<li>Project Manager- South Africa</li>
<li>Consulting Manager- Greece</li>
<li>Senior Consulting Manager- Europe</li>
</ul>
```

this is standard 
what i want to do is to load this data from a text file on the server without using java
is it possible?

I want to link between text file and browser

Comment: Where this text file is located? Do you want to load just once (and store it somewhere) or everytime a page is loaded? What do you mean with _"link between text file and browser"_?

Comment: Voting to close. As comments show up, I have the feeling that it's all about a pointy haired boss trying to keep the intern busy.

Comment: i need to load the text file each time the page load , if its impossible with html , give me some advice for others , JQUERY is alreay done (BOSS dont want to use JQUERY)

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not a programming language. It's a mark-up language designed to define documents and nothing else. You can't write programs in plain HTML.

Now, there *are* some languages that allow to define documents *and* write programs (think of [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript)) but it's not the case of HTML. The additional functionalities you can find in modern web sites is provided by other languages and technologies that interact with HTML: CSS, JavaScript, Java, Flash...

The most obvious tool to accomplish your goals is JavaScript. That's good news because JavaScript is not Java :)

Have a look at this [jQuery example](http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-0) that roughly does what you are asking. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a popular JavaScript library that's quite easy to use.

Comment: YES , ITS ALREADY DONE IN  JQUERY , THIS IS THE CODE

Comment: jQuery.get('/Documents/TEST-SCROLL.txt', function(data) { 
      var myvar = data;


$("#test").html('<a href="#"><li>'+myvar+'</li></a>');
$("#test").simplyScroll({
  autoMode: 'loop'
   });

Comment: BUT MY BOSS WANT TO ME TO SEE IF THERE IS ANOTHER WAY TO DO IT USING HTML OR PHP

Comment: So now it needs to be done in HTML (which is impossible, no matter what your boss says) or PHP. Will this question change many other times?

Comment: what are other solutions , other than JQUERY

Answer (score 0):

You cannot process a text file using HTML alone.

If the text file is located on the server, you either have to use server-side scripting (e.g. PHP) and process it directly or client side scripting (e.g. JavaScript) to download the file from the server and then process it.

Comment: <?PHP

$filename = "file.txt";

$fp = fopen ($filename, "r");
if ($fp) {
$text = fread ($fp, filesize ($filename));
fclose ($fp);
echo $text; // prints text to the screen
}
else {
echo ("File is not readable");
}

?>

Comment: WHERE IS THE PROBLEM  IN HERE?

Comment: The problem is you are writing in caps. No one will listen.

Comment: That could should work quite fine. Although you usually write `<?php`... What errors are you getting? Is PHP installed on the server?

Comment: i am using SharePoint Server 2007 , i write jquery in a webpart so it runs

Comment: but when i write php , it wont run , any ideas ?

Comment: What happens when you run the php script?

Comment: i wrote the PHP in a webpart and run it , nothing happened

Comment: should i add something for the PHP code , before i write it , like a link ot a library or something ?